# Is this dangerous? About events

Tags: c#, .net

Maybe a stupid question, but..

In my code I use the following construction at several places.

```
void MyFunction() 
{
    DoSomething(myClass.myProperty)

    myClass.PropertyChanged += (s,e ) => {
      if (e.PropertyName == "myProperty") {
        DoSomething(myClass.myProperty);
      }
    }
}
```

So I want to do something initially, and also do the same when the property changes in the future.

Now the thing is, MyFunction() gets called several time during my program's execution. Will the delegate I assign to PropertyChanged be added evertime it passes through this method? (consuming more memory every iteration and slowing down the program) Or is the compiler/runtime smart enough to understand I should be only added the first time..? And if so, how does this work?

Comment: It may not be an issue for you, but with this syntax it is not possible to unsubscribe the anonymous eventhandler from this event which may lead to some memory issues.  I'd recommend writing the function, and just attach the eventhandler with the += new eventhandler(function);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the other answers suggest that you should check whether the `PropertyChanged` event is `null` to prevent adding several listeners. A problem with that solution is that `PropertyChanged` can be non-`null` if other parts of the code listens to the same event but for another property, like this.

```
void AnotherFunction() 
{
  myClass.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => {
    if (e.PropertyName == "anotherProperty") {
      DoSomethingElse(myClass.anotherProperty);
    }
  }
}
```

A better solution, in my opinion, would be to maintain a boolean flag which is initially false, and only set to true when `MyFunction` is called. Then, check this flag whether you need to add the event handler.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler can't know your intent ... it will faithfully attach the event handler on each call to MyFunction().

Look at it this way - they compiler can't know that the reference variables (e.g. `myclass`) in your function refer to the same instances of objects you've attached handlers to previously. Nor can it know that you haven't detached the handler somewhere else between calls. It can't make assumptions like this.

You, however, could restructure your code so that the handler is only attached once. Since other consumers may subscribe to the PropertyChanged event, you need to keep some independent state around to know whether you have subscribed or not. For example:

```
if( !haveSubscribedToPropertyChanged ) {
    myClass.PropertyChanged += (s,e ) => {
          if (e.PropertyName == "myProperty") {
                DoSomething(myClass.myProperty);
          }
        }
        haveSubscribedToPropertyChanged = true;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. An issue here is also that myClass is a singleton that may also be accessed from other methods. So others may add they delegates as well. I need to find something for that too..

Comment: The solution of checking for null is not viable for a PropertyChanged event, as other parts of the code may use the same event to listen for changes to different properties. See my answer for different solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158849/is-this-dangerous-about-events/1158930#1158930